# Using boost::program_options

Tags: command-line, boost, command-line-interface, boost-program-options

In my program I have a list of pairs - name and size.

I want to build this list from the command line interface using `boost::program_options`.

It should look something like this:

> myProg --value("John",10) --value("Steve",14) --value("Marge",28)

I also need this to be in order - Steve will be after John and before Marge on the list. Is that possible with `boost::program_options`?

This CLI syntax is just an idea to get the list. If you have a better one, do tell.

Comment: Not really an answer, but according to [this item](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2009/04/46843.php), yo should be fine

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't solve the problem of how to parse each value - we want to extract from each value the name and age, without the need to parse the string ourselves

Comment: `--value("John",10) --value("Steve",14) --value("Marge",28)` is too verbose for the command line, you could use `John 10 Steve 14 "Marge I" 28` (if all these values are optional and there are other required command-line arguments then you could prefix the string with `--values`). The format is concise and is easy to read/write/parse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just define your option

```
("value", value<vector<YourPairType>>()->composing(), "description")
```

and an appropriate

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, YourPairType& pr) { /* ... */ }
```

that reads a single `YourPairType` from `in` in your `("John",10)` format. Parsed options will be stored in the order they appear in the command line.

You can achieve greater flexibility if you use [custom validators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id2075177) instead of `operator >>`.

Answer (score 0):

A file with each line having one pair of values can be one option. The file could be a plain ascii text file or you can go for xml files too - refer to [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).